# Creating SEO urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, seo

I want to create SEO urls for my blogs my blog url is like
http://localhost/test/blog.php?blogId=5 i want to convert it to blogs title.

I am currently trying this in .htaccess page but this didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog.php?blogId=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ blog.php?blogId=$1
```

weird thing is that I tried a similar code for user id's and it worked.

Comment: The myth that rewriting more human readable URLs is better for is SEO is just that... a myth. Modern search engine crawlers do better with dynamic URLs than they do with rewrites. This has been true since 2008. [Read this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html) and [this article](http://searchengineland.com/google-says-dont-rewrite-dynamic-urls-to-static-urls-14795) by Barry Schwartz, Search Engine Land's News Editor and owns a NY based web consulting firm. He also runs Search Engine Roundtable, a popular search blog on very advanced SEM topics.

Comment: You cannot use same pattern `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` for both `profile.php` and `blog.php`

Comment: Also once the rewrite engine is on... it's on. The second declaration needs to be deleted.

Comment: got it i am so dumb, actually i want my blog title to be that blogs url

Answer (score 1):

```
your URL should be 
http://localhost/test/1

RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ blog.php?blogId=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it this way...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L] # for user id's no slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ blog.php?blogId=$1 [NC,L] # for blog with slash
```

A link to a userid would look like `/2`

A link to a blog article would look like `/2/`